# OnChange event is not firing even though it's part of code are working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onchange

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function IP() {
  const [ipAddress, setIPAddress] = useState("");

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const inputValue = event.target.value;
    // Validate the input against IP address pattern
    const isValidIP = /^(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}$/.test(inputValue);

    if (isValidIP) {
      setIPAddress(inputValue);
    }

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        Enter IP Address:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={ipAddress}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
        />
      </label>
      <p>Current IP Address: {ipAddress}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default IP
```

Here as you can see I'm just using regular expression to evaluate the input and to display it but the OnChange is not giving any error nor output. It's not even changing the placeholder.

I tried to execute the regular expression individually and it is giving desired input but when added to my code it's giving me false every single time.

Comment: You should understand that on each letter input your `handleInputChange` will be called and IP will not be validated, and so the value will be blank always as the default state is blank

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Not true. In react: The onChange event behaves as you would expect it to: whenever a form field is changed, this event is fired. It intentionally do not use the existing browser behavior because onChange is a misnomer for its behavior and React relies on this event to handle user input in real time. Taken from the docs: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#onchange

Comment: @Tushar happy to be corrected. I've removed the erroneous comment.

Comment: As pointed out `onChange` doesn't work the same way as standard HTML, it's more like `onInput` here, but if you do want to validate after input you could use `defaultValue` and then the `onBlur` event.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that on each letter input your `handleInputChange` will be called and IP will not be validated, so the value will be blank always as the default state is blank

You need to package you IP address validation with a trigger to

- Either allow the user to input full IP and then validate
- Or have a button that triggers the validation

---

**Context**:

In react, whenever a form field is changed, the onChange event is triggered. : [from docs](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-onchange-events-with-examples)

> The onChange event behaves as you would expect it to: whenever a form
> field is changed, this event is fired. It intentionally do not use the
> existing browser behavior because onChange is a misnomer for its
> behavior and React relies on this event to handle user input in real
> time. Taken from the docs:
> legacy.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#onchange

Answer (score 0):

The reason the input's value doesn't change is that it will only change if a string is valid after comparing against `/^(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}$/` regular expression.
There are 2 approaches to fix this:

1. Execute `setIPAddress(inputValue)` on every `onChange` event, even if `inputValue` is not a valid IP address.
2. If you want to set the value to `ipAddress` only if the string is a valid IP address, then you need to add an extra variable for the input's state exclusively(it has to be executed on every `onChange` event), and the second variable to set the value to only if a string is a valid IP address.

Regarding what approach you choose I recommend you add a mask to the input, it will make UX a way better for the user.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are setting the input only if it is a valid IP. This code => `setIPAddress(e.target.value)` will not be executed until you enter the correct IP. But as a user when you start typing that won't be a valid IP until you enter the whole.

**Solution:** (*`Not tested it, let me know if it does not work`*)

I have created a state errors object(named `errors`) that will keep the form's validation errors.

```
  const [ipAddress, setIPAddress] = useState("");
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const inputValue = event.target.value;
    setIPAddress(inputValue);
    setErrors({...errors, ipAddress: ''});
    const isValidIP = /^(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}$/.test(inputValue);    
    if (!isValidIP) {
       setErrors({...errors, ipAddress: 'Invalid IP'});
    } 
  };

 return (
    <div>
      <label>
        Enter IP Address:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={ipAddress}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
        />
      </label>
      <p>{errors.ipAddress}</p> // show validation error here
      <p>Current IP Address: {ipAddress}</p>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your implementation is that the `ipAddress` value is getting reset every time a user input event is triggered. So, the `isValidIP` regex is always returning false and the IPAddress `p` tag is not showing the IP Address regardless valid or not. Also, the regex has a missing escape for the dot (`.`) value. Correct regex validation will be:

```
const isValidIP = /^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$/.test(inputValue);
```

**Solution Approach**

You can do following steps:

- Add proper escaping of the dot (`.`) character in regex
- Use another useState hook which will store the input state as you type
- If an IP address is valid, then update the original hook value (`ipAddress`) with the new hook value (`userInputValue`), otherwise set it to default placeholder value (`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`)

You can do something like the following:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function IP() {
  const [ipAddress, setIPAddress] = useState("");
  const [userInputValue, setUserInputValue] = useState("");

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const inputValue = event.target.value;
    setUserInputValue(inputValue);

    // Validate the input against IP address pattern
    const isValidIP = /^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$/.test(userInputValue);
    if (isValidIP) {
      setIPAddress(userInputValue);
    } else {
      setIPAddress("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        Enter IP Address:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={userInputValue}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          placeholder="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
        />
      </label>
      <p>Current IP Address: {ipAddress}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default IP;
```

**Explanation**

Here I have used a second useState hook which will update the input as you type. If the regex pattern is matched with the input (that is, when the input is a valid IP Address), the `ipAddress` value will be set to input, and the `p` tag will show the valid IP. In the other case (when an IP address is invalid), the Current IP Address will show the default placeholder value (`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`).